# Dapper custom TypeHandler with DynamicParameters

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm using Dapper in my Web-API project (.NET Core 3.1) and I'm trying to insert a record into a database (SQL Server 2017) + return the created id.
I have this object...

```
public class CreateDetailGroupDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<CreateDetailDto> Details { get; set; }
}
```

and the responsible method looks like this:

```
public async Task<int> Create(CreateDetailGroupDto detailGroup)
{
    using var cnn = Connection;

    var parameter = new DynamicParameters();
    parameter.Add("detailGroup", detailGroup);
    parameter.Add("id", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

    await cnn.ExecuteAsync("spDetailGroup_Insert", param: parameter, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    int id = parameter.Get<int>("id");

    return id;
}
```

I'm executing the stored procedure `spDetailGroup_Insert` which expects the object above in JSON format `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and has the id as an output paramater.
I wrote a handler which is supposed to serialize an object when used as a paramter (I thought):

```
public class TypeHandler<T> : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<T>
{
    public override T Parse(object value)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value.ToString());
    }

    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, T value)
    {
        parameter.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    }
}
```

In the constructor of the class i use `SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new TypeHandler<CreateDetailGroupDto>());` to add the TypeHandler for the DTO. However... when the `Create` methods is run, the object is not converted to JSON, even though the `SetValue` method in the Handler is successfully executed. 
I know this is pretty specific but does anyone have an idea what might be happening here?

**Edit:**
It appears that adding one line in the SetValue method to specify the DbType, seems to fix the issue:

```
public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, T value)
{
    parameter.DbType = DbType.String;
    parameter.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [implementation of DynamicParameters](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/d797c2930dbf15ada575df58a0a9acd33160c0cf/Dapper/DynamicParameters.cs) the DbType defaults to null, so i guess you are missing the DbType-specification in the Add-Method:

```
public async Task<int> Create(CreateDetailGroupDto detailGroup)
{
    using var cnn = Connection;

    var parameter = new DynamicParameters();
    parameter.Add("detailGroup", detailGroup, DbType.String);
    parameter.Add("id", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

    await cnn.ExecuteAsync("spDetailGroup_Insert", param: parameter, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    int id = parameter.Get<int>("id");

    return id;
}
```

The correct mapping of nvarchar(max) should be DbType.String accoring to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings).

Comment: That is true but then i run into the problem that the SetValue method in the handler is not run. I think my problem is very similar to this Issue https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/275.

Comment: By seeing your edit: I was about to suggest to set the DbType in this SetValue using a method, which retrieves the DbType based on a mapping, so you would be more flexible if you want to use the generic TypeHandler for types other than string. But if you wanna stay with string, your solution is fine.